# Spring Boot 2.0.0.M2/Spring Data and findById method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm trying to move my project to `Spring Boot 2.0.0.M2`

Now Spring Data uses `Optional` for findBy* methods, like:

```
Optional<T> findById(ID id);
```

I have a Neo4j entities that contain the `id` property, for example:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Tag {

    private Long id;

}

@Repository
public interface TagRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Tag, Long>

    Tag findById(Long tagId);

}
```

`id` is a plain property and not and entity identifier(PK).

Prior Spring Boot 2.0 I used `repository.findOne()` embedded method in order to look up entity by it's identifier(PK) and my custom `repository.findById()` in order to look up entity by its `id` property.

Right now with Spring Boot 2.0 we don't have `findOne` and instead of this we have findById method finds the entity by PK. Right now I don't know how to provide my custom `repository.findById` method i order to be able to look up entity by ID property(not PK). Please advise.

Comment: Can't you just write another method and annotate it with `@Query`? Or just do the right thing, and rename your id property to something less confusing, since it's... not an ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field `tagId` exists in the entity you can use

```
Tag findByTagId(long tagId);
```

if not use

```
@Query("select t from Tag t where t.tagId = :tagId")
Tag getByTagId(@Param("tagId") long tagId);
```

Comment: Are you sure `findById` without `@Query` declared does the same thing at Spring Data Neo4j like for example `@Query("MATCH (t:Tag) where t.id = {tagId} RETURN t")` ?

Comment: SImple `getById` (without `@Query` over) instead of `findById` in `TagRepository` did the trick.